# How to Unquote a string and insert it into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

i am having one problem with data insertion.
i have a column which contains quoted strings and using php i am inserting those values into another table.the problem occurs with quoted values and others are inserting fine.
is there any way to unquote that and insert or make it possible using php.
thanks in advance...

Comment: Please escape string using mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Another option would be to use prepare statment

Comment: Fix the problem at its root e.g dont quote the strings before insert. Use PDO or mysqli with prepared query's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
   $myusername = $_POST["user"];
   $mypassword = $_POST["pass"];        

   $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
   $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

   $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' 
        and password='$mypassword'";
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

This protects against mysql injection

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli::real_escape_string($string);` Here is a [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to the documentation.

Comment: where he specified that he is using mysqli extension ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the regular `mysql_*` functions, you can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape the strings. Otherwise you can prepare the statement.

If using mysqli, you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or the static method `mysql::escape_string()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php